# toc plus appedix toc

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, appendices, tocloft

first things first. I'm writing my master's thesis with latex. (scrbook, pdflatex)

My institute has some strict regulations on the occurence of toc and appendix toc. Generally it should look like this: https://pl.vc/5vke0
Header is in 14pt bold, everything else 12pt regular. So I need two toc, one for the content and one for the appendix. The wired part is, I need both of them in the beginning of my document like it's shown in the link's picture plus only the appendix toc in front of my appendix.

I found kind of solution with koma-script (http://www.komascript.de/comment/3447#comment-3447) but i can't format everything to my satisfaction. Does anyone know a solution how to solve that problem with latex?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: There is no MWE in the question so I do not know which code from [Anhangsverzeichnis](http://www.komascript.de/node/458) do you use. As I have understand from your question on the [KOMA-Script website](http://www.komascript.de) you want something like that

[image][image]

Here is a suggestion to get this ugly result:

```
% based on http://www.komascript.de/node/458 but with ugly modifications
\documentclass[parskip=full-]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\newtocstyle[KOMAlike][leaders]{KOMAlikewithdot}{}% Neuen Stil abgeleitet von
                                % KOMAlike erstellen, wobei das Feature
                                % leaders nicht von KOMAlike mit übernommen
                                % wird.
                                % (tocstyle.pdf, 2009/11/09, Seite 9 sowie 
                                % Seite 29, Code-Zeile 772)
\usetocstyle{KOMAlikewithdot}
\settocfeature[lof]{entryhook}{\noindent Abb.\nobreakspace}% (tocstyle.pdf, 2009/11/09,
                                % Seite 8)
\settocfeature[lot]{entryhook}{\noindent Tab.\nobreakspace}% (tocstyle.pdf, 2009/11/09,
                                % Seite 8)

\makeatletter
% Die folgende Anweisung wird vermutlich irgendwann in scrlfile.sty eingebaut.
% Bis dahin ist es notwendig, sie selbst zu definieren, damit man innerhalb
% von \BeforeClosingMainAux \addtocontents verwenden kann:
\providecommand{\protected@immediate@write}[3]{%
  \begingroup
    \let\thepage\relax
    #2%
    \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
    \edef\reserved@a{\immediate\write#1{#3}}%
    \reserved@a
  \endgroup
  \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}

% Die folgende Umgebung wird verwendet, um innerhalb der toc-Datei einzelne
% Bereiche ein- und ausschalten zu können. In die toc-Datei wird die Umgebung
% dabei jeweils als \begin{tocconditional}{BEREICH}...\end{tocconditional}
% eingefügt.
\newenvironment*{tocconditional}[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname if@toccond@#1\expandafter\endcsname
                  \csname iftrue\endcsname
  \else
    \value{tocdepth}=-10000\relax
  \fi
  \typeout{tocdepth in `#1': \the\c@tocdepth}%
}{%
}

% Gleich nach dem Öffnen der toc-Datei beginnen wir den Haupt-Bereich "main":
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\begin{tocconditional}{main}}
}
% Und der letzte Bereich endet am Ende der toc-Datei.
\BeforeClosingMainAux{%
  \begingroup
    \let\protected@write\protected@immediate@write
    \addtocontents{toc}{\string\end{tocconditional}}%
  \endgroup
}

% Hier können nunr neue Bereiche definiert ...
\newcommand*{\newtocconditional}[2][false]{%
  \expandafter\newif\csname if@toccond@#2\endcsname
  \csname @toccond@#2#1\endcsname
}
% Und ein- oder ausgeschaltet werden:
\newcommand*{\settocconditional}[2]{%
  \csname @toccond@#1#2\endcsname
}

% Neben dem Hauptbereich ...
\newtocconditional[true]{main}
% definieren wir noch einen Bereich für den Anhang.
\newtocconditional{appendix}

% Mit dem Anhang geben wir einerseits das Anhangsverzeichnis aus,
% andererseits beenden wir den aktuellen Bereich in der toc-Datei und beginnen
% den neuen Bereich "appendix". Damit im Haupt-Inhaltsverzeichnis ein Eintrag
% für das Anhangsverzeichnis erscheint, verwenden wir \addchap und zwar noch
% bevor der letzte Bereich geschlossen wird. Wenn wir es ganz sicher machen
% wollten, müssten wir die auskommentierten Zeilen noch aktivieren. So
% verlassen wir uns einfach darauf, dass vor dem appendix-Bereich der
% main-Bereich lag.
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
%  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\end{tocconditional}^^J
%    \string\begin{tocconditional}{main}}%
  %\addchap{Anhang}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\end{tocconditional}^^J
    \string\begin{tocconditional}{appendix}}%
  \cleardoubleoddpage
  \addchap*{Anhang}\thispagestyle{empty}
  \appendixtableofcontents
  \cleardoubleoddpage
  \setcounter{page}{1}
  \renewcommand\thepage{A-\arabic{page}}
}

% Jetzt definieren wir das Anhangsverzeichnis selbst als Alias für die
% toc-Datei. Dabei wird aber der Hauptbereich "main" deaktiviert und der
% Anhangsbereich "appendix" aktiviert.
\newcommand*{\appendixtableofcontents}{%
  \showtoc[{ %
    \aliastoc{\tocstyleTOC}{toc}%
    \settocconditional{main}{false}%
    \settocconditional{appendix}{true}%
  }]{toc}%
}

% Auch wenn man einen Anhang normalerweise nicht beenden kann, so ist es
% ggf. erwünscht, dass Literaturverzeichnis, Index etc. zwar nach den Kapiteln
% des Anhangs kommen, aber dem Hauptverzeichnis zugeordnet werden sollen. Also
% benötigen wir eine Anweisung, um in der toc-Datei den aktuellen Bereich zu
% beenden und wieder einen Hauptbereich einzuschalten:
\newcommand*{\postappendix}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\end{tocconditional}^^J%
      \string\begin{tocconditional}{main}}%
  \clearpage
}

\makeatother

\setkomafont{chapterentry}{\normalfont\normalsize}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
{\renewcommand\clearpage{}
\addchap*{Anhang}}
\appendixtableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\blinddocument
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \captionsetup{type=figure}
  Bild
  \caption{Ein Bild}
\end{minipage}

\blindtext

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \captionsetup{type=table}
  Tabelle
  \caption{Eine Tabelle}
\end{minipage}

\appendix
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A\arabic{chapter}}
\chapter{Anhang 1}
\blindtext
\section{Ein Abschnitt im Anhang}
\blindtext
\section{Ein zweiter Abschnitt im Anhang}
\blindtext
\chapter{Anhang 2}
\blindtext
\postappendix

\end{document}
```

Comment: So this is basically a crosspost? Nice, i like crossposts. they are super great.

Comment: Yes, it is a crosspost and I think Markus will be happy that I answer here ;-)

Comment: I am sure he will be happy, but crossposts should be marked as such.